# Getting "user defined type not defined" when trying to use WinSCP .NET assembly in VBA to upload file to SFTP

Tags: vba, excel, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

I am trying to develop code for save the file in SFTP server but error in `Session` and showing error as

> user defined type not defined

I am not sure below code working or not and I copied the code from internet source.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

```
Sub test()
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = "D:\Ashok\Work\Loan_Input_Template V8-Library.xlsx"
Dim mySession As New Session

    ' Enable custom error handling
    On Error Resume Next

    Call Upload(mySession, wb)

    ' Query for errors
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Description

        ' Clear the error
        Err.Clear
    End If

    ' Disconnect, clean up
    mySession.Dispose

    ' Restore default error handling
    On Error GoTo 0

            wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

'FileSystemObject.DeleteFile sPathName

End Sub


Private Sub Upload(ByRef mySession As Session, ByRef wb1 As Workbook) 'error line
 Dim wb As Workbook
 Set wb = Workbooks(wb1)
    ' Setup session options
    Dim mySessionOptions As New SessionOptions
    With mySessionOptions
        .Protocol = Protocol_SFTP
        .HostName = "103.231.8.66"
        .UserName = "username"
        .Password = "password"
        .SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-ed25519 256 df:94:44:56:1b:c2:75:8b:b4:58:3a:e2:ef:2e:0d:78"
    End With

    ' Connect
    mySession.Open mySessionOptions

    ' Upload files
    Dim myTransferOptions As New TransferOptions
    myTransferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode_Binary

    Dim transferResult As TransferOperationResult
    Set transferResult = mySession.PutFiles(wb1, "/home/sftpcf/", False, myTransferOptions)

    ' Throw on any error
    transferResult.Check

    ' Display results
    Dim transfer As TransferEventArgs
    For Each transfer In transferResult.Transfers
        MsgBox "Upload of " & transfer.FileName & " succeeded"
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line returns the error?

Comment: Did you first follow the steps as outlined here: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_vb ?

Comment: @destination-data  `Private Sub Upload(ByRef mySession As Session, ByRef wb1 As Workbook)`

Comment: As LocEngineer say - I suspect you've missed this: In Microsoft Visual Basic editor, go to Tools > References, check reference to WinSCP scripting interface .NET wrapper and confirm with OK.

Comment: @LocEngineer - i did that code copied from there only

Comment: @Ashok then follow the steps described in that link. Register Winscp for COM, then in VBA go to References and check Winscp

Comment: @HarassedDad i can't find .NET wrapper for WinSCP console interfac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have followed the instructions for:

- [Installing the WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_install) and
- [Registering it for COM](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_install#registering) and
- [Using it from VBA](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_vb#using).

Comment: i register below way whereas that library ` WinSCP scripting interface .NET` not available in the Available list in the tool.                       >C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCPWinSCPnet.dll" <C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCPWinSCPnet.dll"

Comment: Edit your question to show what **exactly** have you done.

Comment: please look above

Comment: register successfully done but not showing in the list

Comment: Did you restart Excel?

Comment: Watch your words!

Comment: is there any other way to add the that library in excel or msoffice?

Comment: And show us what did you do exactly, including the output. The command in your first comment has invalid syntax.

Comment: oh sorry for 'DUDE'

Comment: forgot to mention \ in WinSCP\WinSCPnet.dll

Comment: refer the link of both error and successfully register imges-[Inline Link](https://ibb.co/kNJnjm) - [Inline Link] ( https://ibb.co/hb9oqR)

Comment: The first link does not show successful registration and the second link does not show a command.

Comment: refer this link fully show to command [Inline Link] (https://ibb.co/c3nPVR)

Comment: is there any problem while on register ?

Comment: is it possible that do the code in powershall via vba?

Comment: That's not the correct registration command. Again, read section on [Registering for COM](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_install#registering).

Comment: i tried but not able to successful that way- showing error  `RegAsm : error RA0000 : Unable to locate input assembly 'WinSCPnet.dll' or one of its dependencies.`

Comment: Again, as the documentation says: *"The above examples assume that `WinSCPnet.dll` is in current working directory. Otherwise you need to specify an absolute path to the `.dll`."* (i.e. the same way you did in your previous attempt).

Comment: extremely sorry for asking question. i did this way 'C:\>%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCPnet.dll/codebase /tlb:WinSCPnet32.tlb` but showing error `RegAsm : error RA0000 : Unable to locate input assembly 'C:\Program' or one of its dependencies.`

Comment: `%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCPnet.dll" /codebase /tlb:WinSCPnet32.tlb`