# Not able to connect to FTP server using "wininet.dll" in VBA but can connect with WinSCP

Tags: excel, vba, ftp, winscp, wininet

I'm using below code snippet to connect to a server using `wininet.dll` in VBA but not able to connect to that. But when I try to connect to the server using WinSCP 5.15.1, it's able to connect. And when I try to use 5.5.5.0 version of WinSCP, it shows error *"Couldn't agree a key exchange algorithm"*. 
It also shows login error when I try to connect it using `ftp` command in `cmd`.

I'm wondering is it possible to connect to the server using `wininet.dll` in VBA by fixing any thing.

```
Public Function checkFTPpath(ByVal ServerName, ByVal Username, ByVal password, ByVal remote_path) As Boolean

  Dim hostFile As String
  Dim INet As Long
  Dim INetConn As Long
  Dim RetVal As Long
  Dim Success As Boolean

  Success = False
  RetVal = False
  INet = InternetOpen("MyFTP Control", 1&, vbNullString, vbNullString, 0&)
  If INet > 0 Then
    INetConn = InternetConnect(INet, ServerName, 21, Username, password, 1&, 0&, 0&)
      If INetConn > 0 Then
          Success = FtpSetCurrentDirectory(INetConn, "/")
          Success = FtpSetCurrentDirectory(INetConn, remote_path)
        RetVal = InternetCloseHandle(INetConn)
      End If
      RetVal = InternetCloseHandle(INet)
  End If
  checkFTPpath = Success

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

If you get *"Couldn't agree a key exchange algorithm"* in WinSCP, it means that you are using SFTP protocol, not FTP. Wininet *speaks* FTP only, not SFTP.

You will have to use SFTP library. See [SFTP upload in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52131131/850848).

Comment: I only need to check whether a particular path exists. Could you please suggest me the best way to check in VBA?

Comment: I have answered your question about *"Not able to connect using “wininet.dll” in VBA"*. If you have a new problem now, please post a new question.